# Android record audio and store to root directory

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am trying to record audio and I would like to store file inside my application.

Currently, I am saving to SD card like this.

```
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

May I know how to store file inside application? How many type of directory can be used to save audio file?

Comment: I'm sorry to point to just the documentation, but... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: it is useful for me. Thanks :)